# how to detect reject in walletconnect?

Tags: ethers.js, walletconnect

hi I'm trying to detect if user rejects the connect request or transaction request in his wallet app and I detect it and show something in website but it's not returning anything and it closes QR modal

```
const provider = new WalletConnectProvider({
        rpc: {
          56: "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"
      },
      chainId: 56,
      });
provider.enable()
```

I'm using Ethers JS and Walletconnect